# Sections of (affine) toric varieties by linear subspaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a reference that expands on the following statement:

"Sections of toric varieties by linear subspaces defined by coordinates or differences of coordinates are binomial schemes." [page 2 in "Binomial Ideals" by Eisenbud, Sturmfels, 1994].

Is there a source that expands on this point?

Are there other sources working out the sections of toric varieties by linear subspaces? I am looking both for explicit work akin to [Eisenbud, Sturmfels] as well as sources using intersection theory.

My motivation is to understand the sections of toric varieties arising in toric dynamical systems by linear spaces [Craciun, Gheorghe, et al. "Toric dynamical systems." Journal of Symbolic Computation 44.11 (2009): 1551-1565.] because they have biophysical significance. Moreover, I am interested in the linear subspaces contained in such varieties.